# I want to set time using buttons in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following javascript code and it is working fine as to increasing and decreasing the values.

```js
function increaseH1() {
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('H1').value, 10);
  value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
  value++;
  document.getElementById('H1').value = value;
}
function increaseH2() {
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('H2').value, 10);
  value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
  value++;
  document.getElementById('H2').value = value;
}
function increaseM1() {
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('M1').value, 10);
  value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
  value++;
  document.getElementById('M1').value = value;
}
function increaseM2() {
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('M2').value, 10);
  value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
  value++;
  document.getElementById('M2').value = value;
}


function decreaseH1() {
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('H1').value, 10);
  value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
  value < 1 ? value = 1 : '';
  value--;
  document.getElementById('H1').value = value;
}
function decreaseH2() {
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('H2').value, 10);
  value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
  value < 1 ? value = 1 : '';
  value--;
  document.getElementById('H2').value = value;
}
function decreaseM1() {
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('M1').value, 10);
  value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
  value < 1 ? value = 1 : '';
  value--;
  document.getElementById('M1').value = value;
}
function decreaseM2() {
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('M2').value, 10);
  value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
  value < 1 ? value = 1 : '';
  value--;
  document.getElementById('M2').value = value;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" align="center">
  <tr>
  <td width="20%"><img class="triangle" src="http://www.trzcacak.rs/file/max/0/7319_square-png.png" onclick="increaseH1()"></td>
  <td width="20%"><img class="triangle" src="http://www.trzcacak.rs/file/max/0/7319_square-png.png" onclick="increaseH2()"></td>
  <td width="10%"></td>
  <td width="20%"><img class="triangle" src="http://www.trzcacak.rs/file/max/0/7319_square-png.png" onclick="increaseM1()"></td>
  <td width="20%"><img class="triangle" src="http://www.trzcacak.rs/file/max/0/7319_square-png.png" onclick="increaseM2()"></td>
  </tr>
  <script src="/assets/triangle.js"></script>
  <tr>  
  <td><input readonly="true" style="font-size:22pt; text-align:center;" id="H1" type="number" name="timer-on-hour1" value="1" min="0" max="1"></td>
  <td><input readonly="true" style="font-size:22pt; text-align:center;" id="H2" type="number" name="timer-on-hour2" value="2" min="0" max="9"></td>
  <td><h2 class="options"><font size="8">:</font></h2></td>
  <td><input readonly="true" style="font-size:22pt; text-align:center;" id="M1" type="number" name="timer-on-minute1" value="5" min="0" max="5"></td>
  <td><input readonly="true" style="font-size:22pt; text-align:center;" id="M2" type="number" name="timer-on-minute2" value="9" min="0" max="9"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><img class="triangle" src="http://www.trzcacak.rs/file/max/0/7319_square-png.png" onclick="decreaseH1()"></td>
  <td><img class="triangle" src="http://www.trzcacak.rs/file/max/0/7319_square-png.png" onclick="decreaseH2()"></td>
  <td></td>
  <td><img class="triangle" src="http://www.trzcacak.rs/file/max/0/7319_square-png.png" onclick="decreaseM1()"></td>
  <td><img class="triangle" src="http://www.trzcacak.rs/file/max/0/7319_square-png.png" onclick="decreaseM2()"></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
```

The issue I am having is limiting the inputs not being more than 12:00.

Comment: What about am and pm, this solves anything larger than 12.

Comment: So this is a 24hr clock (not 12hr)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated you code to restrict time to 12:00.

```js
function increaseH1() {
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('H1').value, 10);
  value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
  value++;
  if(value>1){ value=0; }
  document.getElementById('H1').value = value;
}
function increaseH2() {
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('H2').value, 10);
  value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
  value++;
  if(value>9){ value=0; }
  document.getElementById('H2').value = value;
}
function increaseM1() {
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('M1').value, 10);
  value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
  value++;
  if(value>9){ value=0; }
  document.getElementById('M1').value = value;
}
function increaseM2() {
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('M2').value, 10);
  value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
  value++;
  if(value>9){ value=0; }
  document.getElementById('M2').value = value;
}


function decreaseH1() {
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('H1').value, 10);
  value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
  value < 1 ? value = 1 : '';
  value--;
  document.getElementById('H1').value = value;
}
function decreaseH2() {
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('H2').value, 10);
  value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
  value < 1 ? value = 1 : '';
  value--;
  document.getElementById('H2').value = value;
}
function decreaseM1() {
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('M1').value, 10);
  value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
  value < 1 ? value = 1 : '';
  value--;
  document.getElementById('M1').value = value;
}
function decreaseM2() {
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('M2').value, 10);
  value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
  value < 1 ? value = 1 : '';
  value--;
  document.getElementById('M2').value = value;
}

function minutLimit(){
  var h1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('H1').value, 10);
  var h2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('H2').value, 10);
  var c = parseInt(h1+''+h2);
  console.log(c);
  if(h2>=9){
   return false;  
  }else if(c>=12){
   return false;  
  }
  return true;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" align="center">
  <tr>
  <td width="20%"><img class="triangle" src="http://www.trzcacak.rs/file/max/0/7319_square-png.png" onclick="increaseH1()"></td>
  <td width="20%"><img class="triangle" src="http://www.trzcacak.rs/file/max/0/7319_square-png.png" onclick="increaseH2()"></td>
  <td width="10%"></td>
  <td width="20%"><img class="triangle" src="http://www.trzcacak.rs/file/max/0/7319_square-png.png" onclick="increaseM1()"></td>
  <td width="20%"><img class="triangle" src="http://www.trzcacak.rs/file/max/0/7319_square-png.png" onclick="increaseM2()"></td>
  </tr>
  <script src="/assets/triangle.js"></script>
  <tr>  
  <td><input readonly="true" style="font-size:22pt; text-align:center;" id="H1" type="number" name="timer-on-hour1" value="1" min="0" max="1"></td>
  <td><input readonly="true" style="font-size:22pt; text-align:center;" id="H2" type="number" name="timer-on-hour2" value="2" min="0" max="9"></td>
  <td><h2 class="options"><font size="8">:</font></h2></td>
  <td><input readonly="true" style="font-size:22pt; text-align:center;" id="M1" type="number" name="timer-on-minute1" value="5" min="0" max="5"></td>
  <td><input readonly="true" style="font-size:22pt; text-align:center;" id="M2" type="number" name="timer-on-minute2" value="9" min="0" max="9"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><img class="triangle" src="http://www.trzcacak.rs/file/max/0/7319_square-png.png" onclick="decreaseH1()"></td>
  <td><img class="triangle" src="http://www.trzcacak.rs/file/max/0/7319_square-png.png" onclick="decreaseH2()"></td>
  <td></td>
  <td><img class="triangle" src="http://www.trzcacak.rs/file/max/0/7319_square-png.png" onclick="decreaseM1()"></td>
  <td><img class="triangle" src="http://www.trzcacak.rs/file/max/0/7319_square-png.png" onclick="decreaseM2()"></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function increaseH1() {
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('H1').value, 10);
  var H2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('H2').value, 10);
  value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
 if(H2 >= 2){
  document.getElementById('M1').value = 0;
  document.getElementById('M2').value = 0;
  document.getElementById('H2').value = 2;
  if(value < 1) { 
   value++;
   document.getElementById('H1').value = value;
  }
 } else if(H2 < 2){
  if(value < 1) { 
   value++;
   document.getElementById('H1').value = value;
  }
 }
 
}

function increaseH2() {
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('H2').value, 10);
  var H1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('H1').value, 10);
  var M1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('M1').value, 10);
  var M2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('M2').value, 10);
  value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
 switch(H1){
  case 1:
   if(value < 2) { 
    value++;
    document.getElementById('H2').value = value;
   }
   break;
  case 0:
   if(value < 9) { 
    value++;
    document.getElementById('H2').value = value;
   }
 }
 if(value + H1 == 3 && value < 3){
  document.getElementById('M1').value = 0;
  document.getElementById('M2').value = 0;
 }
 
} 




function increaseM1() {
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('M1').value, 10);
  var H2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('H2').value, 10);
  var H1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('H1').value, 10);
  value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
 if (H1 + H2 !== 3 && H1 <= 1 || H2 == 3){
  if(value < 5) { 
   value++;
   document.getElementById('M1').value = value;
  }
 }
}



function increaseM2() {
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('M2').value, 10);
  var H2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('H2').value, 10);
  var H1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('H1').value, 10);
  value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
 if (H1 + H2 !== 3 && H1 <= 1 || H2 == 3){
  if(value < 9) { 
   value++;
   document.getElementById('M2').value = value;
  }
 }
}







function decreaseH1() {
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('H1').value, 10);
  value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
  value < 1 ? value = 1 : '';
  value--;
  document.getElementById('H1').value = value;
}
function decreaseH2() {
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('H2').value, 10);
  value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
  value < 1 ? value = 1 : '';
  value--;
  document.getElementById('H2').value = value;
}
function decreaseM1() {
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('M1').value, 10);
  value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
  value < 1 ? value = 1 : '';
  value--;
  document.getElementById('M1').value = value;
}
function decreaseM2() {
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('M2').value, 10);
  value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
  value < 1 ? value = 1 : '';
  value--;
  document.getElementById('M2').value = value;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" align="center">
  <tr>
  <td width="20%"><img class="triangle" src="http://www.trzcacak.rs/file/max/0/7319_square-png.png" onclick="increaseH1()"></td>
  <td width="20%"><img class="triangle" src="http://www.trzcacak.rs/file/max/0/7319_square-png.png" onclick="increaseH2()"></td>
  <td width="10%"></td>
  <td width="20%"><img class="triangle" src="http://www.trzcacak.rs/file/max/0/7319_square-png.png" onclick="increaseM1()"></td>
  <td width="20%"><img class="triangle" src="http://www.trzcacak.rs/file/max/0/7319_square-png.png" onclick="increaseM2()"></td>
  </tr>
  <script src="/assets/triangle.js"></script>
  <tr>  
  <td><input readonly="true" style="font-size:22pt; text-align:center;" id="H1" type="number" name="timer-on-hour1" value="0" min="0" max="1"></td>
  <td><input readonly="true" style="font-size:22pt; text-align:center;" id="H2" type="number" name="timer-on-hour2" value="0" min="0" max="9"></td>
  <td><h2 class="options"><font size="8">:</font></h2></td>
  <td><input readonly="true" style="font-size:22pt; text-align:center;" id="M1" type="number" name="timer-on-minute1" value="0" min="0" max="5"></td>
  <td><input readonly="true" style="font-size:22pt; text-align:center;" id="M2" type="number" name="timer-on-minute2" value="0" min="0" max="9"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><img class="triangle" src="http://www.trzcacak.rs/file/max/0/7319_square-png.png" onclick="decreaseH1()"></td>
  <td><img class="triangle" src="http://www.trzcacak.rs/file/max/0/7319_square-png.png" onclick="decreaseH2()"></td>
  <td></td>
  <td><img class="triangle" src="http://www.trzcacak.rs/file/max/0/7319_square-png.png" onclick="decreaseM1()"></td>
  <td><img class="triangle" src="http://www.trzcacak.rs/file/max/0/7319_square-png.png" onclick="decreaseM2()"></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
```